# What is the man page for shell scripting file conditions

Tags: linux, unix

I know there is a man page describing available file conditions on *nix systems. What is that man page?

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell_Scripting/Control_flow#Test:_evaluating_conditions

The link above contains a section of file conditions. This is the information I am looking for on my system.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, this is a legitimate question, and I think the test man page is not an obvious one I would find, especially when the description is "condition evaluation utility"

Comment: Hi Derek! I'll take a guess and say this question was downvoted because it's simply a matter of reading the manual. Basically, you were looking at a page that explains how to use the `test` command, and you didn't look at `man test`—that's what's meant by "research effort", shown in the tooltip at the down vote button. In the future, please don't flag for moderator attention though for such minor things. These should be used for exceptions, but down votes happen all the time, and if you seek further advice from the community, drop a question in [chat] or possibly [meta]. Hope that helped!

Comment: That's actually incorrect. What i was looking for is what man page to look up. In other words, I needed to know that "test" is the man page I was looking for.

Comment: Well, take a look at the link you posted: *> There is a tool for exactly this purpose called `test`*, so you wanted the manpage for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The man page I usually refer to for this is [test(1)](http://www.pkill.info/linux/man/1p-test/).

Comment: For the OP: Note that `test` and `[` are often the same.

Comment: Wow - thanks..this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It's in `man bash`.

[Here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) is a cross-section:

```
Conditional Expressions

Conditional expressions are used by the [[ compound command and the test and [ builtin commands to test file attributes and perform string and arithmetic comparisons. Expressions are formed from the following unary or binary primaries. If any file argument to one of the primaries is of the form /dev/fd/n, then file descriptor n is checked. If the file argument to one of the primaries is one of /dev/stdin, /dev/stdout, or /dev/stderr, file descriptor 0, 1, or 2, respectively, is checked.

Unless otherwise specified, primaries that operate on files follow symbolic links and operate on the target of the link, rather than the link itself.

When used with [[, The < and > operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.

-a file
True if file exists.
-b file
True if file exists and is a block special file.
-c file
True if file exists and is a character special file.
-d file
True if file exists and is a directory.
-e file
True if file exists.
-f file
True if file exists and is a regular file.
-g file
True if file exists and is set-group-id.
-h file
True if file exists and is a symbolic link.
...
```

Another option for just the evaluations is `man test` which is just the conditions.

Comment: Are those supposed to apply across all shells? I am using bourne shell.

Comment: There are probably lots of similarities, but other shells *may* have other options.  Are you in Bourne or Bourne Again?

Comment: I am in bourne shell. I know there is a specific man page for file conditions without having to wade through the rest of the man page for the shell, because I was on it at one point, but lost my history and can't remember it.